# How to get skype contact list from a browser?

Tags: api, rest, skype, skype4com, contact-list

I want to get my skype contact list in a browser page just like https://imo.im/ does it.

How the skype api works? For me it's really confusing. As I see I need to download skype4com to make it work with PHP or node.js etc?

How is that working?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at https://github.com/ShyykoSerhiy/skyweb (https://www.npmjs.com/package/skyweb).

```
import Skyweb = require('../skyweb');

var skyweb = new Skyweb();
skyweb.login('skypeUsername', 'skypePassword').then((skypeAccount) => {
    console.log('Your contacts : ' + JSON.stringify(skyweb.contactsService.contacts, null, 2));
});
```

Note that skyweb relies on some internal parts Skype for Web (web.skype.com) implementation and this approach may stop working literally in any moment.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, do Ctrl+U to view the source code, or (better method) do Ctrl+Q above your contact list and see if there is a term you can process via preg_match or preg_match_all